# How to scrape the hotel category type in booking.com?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am **scraping** booking.com for my academic project. I need to scrape hotel category type, whether the given hotel is hotel or apartment hotel or villa etc.. Each hotel is going to the new link and the categories are available in two different classes for each hotel.

I used selenium web driver and beautiful soup but my results are not correct and also getting  class is not found (error message: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[@class = 'bui-badge bh-property-type bh-property-type--constructive-dark'])

**Class 1 in the booking.com**

[image: class 1]

**Class 2 in the booking.com**

[image]

```
#Importing necessary library

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import requests

from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest
from itertools import zip_longest
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


useragent = UserAgent()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent.random)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

names = []
links = []


driver.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&lang=en-gb&sid=643f8d88e23b09ce396d7959aaad4b9e&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ%3Bsid%3D643f8d88e23b09ce396d7959aaad4b9e%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Auckland&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Auckland&ssne_untouched=Auckland&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=7&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=7&checkout_monthday=15&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1")
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#Getting the hotel name

for item in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'sr-hotel__name'}):
        names.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
#Getting the link of each hotel
for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'hotel_name_link url'}):
        item = item.get("href").strip("\n")
        links.append(f"https://www.booking.com{item}")
        

final = []
for item in zip_longest(names, links):
    final.append(item)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(
    final, columns=['Names', 'links'])


#Getting the hotel category by opening each hotel link

category = []

for item in df5['links']:
    
    driver.get(item)
    time.sleep(2)
    
# Extracting from class 1
    try:
        job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'hp__hotel-type-badge']").text
        category.append(job_title)
# Extracting from class 2 
    except:
        job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'bui-badge bh-property-type bh-property-type--constructive-dark']").text
        category.append(job_title)
```

I was tryng to extract the category names for last two days but not successful. Please help.

Comment: The bui-badge bh-property-type wasn't found on some pages and I'd suggest checking to see if the element exists before appending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and then get the category name.I have tested on chrome browser.It is working fine.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

#downlod the compatible chrome driver from following website  https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver")
names = []
links = []

driver.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&lang=en-gb&sid=643f8d88e23b09ce396d7959aaad4b9e&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-gb.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ%3Bsid%3D643f8d88e23b09ce396d7959aaad4b9e%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Auckland&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Auckland&ssne_untouched=Auckland&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=7&checkin_monthday=1&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=7&checkout_monthday=15&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1")
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#Getting the hotel name

for item in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'sr-hotel__name'}):
        names.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
#Getting the link of each hotel
for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'hotel_name_link url'}):
        item = item.get("href").strip()
        links.append("https://www.booking.com{}".format(item))

print(links)

final = []
for item in zip_longest(names, links):
    final.append(item)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(
    final, columns=['Names', 'links'])


#Getting the hotel category by opening each hotel link

category = []

for item in df5['links']:

    driver.get(item)
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2#hp_hotel_name")))

# Extracting from class 1
    try:
        job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'hp__hotel-type-badge']").text
        category.append(job_title)
# Extracting from class 2
    except:
        job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'bui-badge bh-property-type bh-property-type--constructive-dark']").text
        category.append(job_title)


print(category)
```

**Output**:

Links:

```
['https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/naumi-auckland-airport.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4327023_207636943_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=1&highlighted_blocks=4327023_207636943_2_2_0&hpos=1&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4327023_207636943_2_2_0__187720&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/kiwi-international-airport.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4307307_248627375_2_34_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=2&highlighted_blocks=4307307_248627375_2_34_0&hpos=2&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4307307_248627375_2_34_0__156800&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/oaks-smartstay-residence.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=3715901_195766824_0_0_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=3&highlighted_blocks=3715901_195766824_0_0_0&hpos=3&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=3715901_195766824_0_0_0__194400&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=;has_campaign_deals_getaway20_customer_label=1#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/kiwi-international.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4306910_145188713_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=4&highlighted_blocks=4306910_145188713_2_2_0&hpos=4&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4306910_145188713_2_2_0__82600&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/airport-garden-inn-amp-conference-centre.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=368872401_119516889_0_2_3&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=5&highlighted_blocks=368872401_119516889_0_2_3&hpos=5&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=368872401_119516889_0_2_3__132300&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=;has_campaign_deals_getaway20_customer_label=1#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/jet-park-airport-conference-centre.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4323907_132260303_0_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=6&highlighted_blocks=4323907_132260303_0_2_0&hpos=6&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4323907_132260303_0_2_0__186728&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/ventura-inn-suites-auckland-airport.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4322906_148307165_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=7&highlighted_blocks=4322906_148307165_2_2_0&hpos=7&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4322906_148307165_2_2_0__197460&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/airport-gateway.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4649004_248627361_3_34_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=8&highlighted_blocks=4649004_248627361_3_34_0&hpos=8&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4649004_248627361_3_34_0__235200&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/auckland-airport-motel.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=26933802_248627359_4_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=9&highlighted_blocks=26933802_248627359_4_2_0&hpos=9&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=26933802_248627359_4_2_0__224000&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/grand-chancellor-auckland-city.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4312701_199559564_0_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=10&highlighted_blocks=4312701_199559564_0_2_0&hpos=10&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4312701_199559564_0_2_0__245310&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/aucklands-waitakaere-estate.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=25639707_92677386_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=11&highlighted_blocks=25639707_92677386_2_2_0&hpos=11&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=25639707_92677386_2_2_0__237204&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/formule1-auckland.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=31939007_94407293_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=12&highlighted_blocks=31939007_94407293_2_2_0&hpos=12&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=31939007_94407293_2_2_0__210000&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/novotel-auckland-airport.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=27270502_95454373_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=13&highlighted_blocks=27270502_95454373_2_2_0&hpos=13&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=27270502_95454373_2_2_0__352600&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/president-hotel-auckland.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4310701_250543755_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=14&highlighted_blocks=4310701_250543755_2_2_0&hpos=14&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4310701_250543755_2_2_0__126350&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/auckland-airport-traveller-39-s-international-motor-inn.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=101416508_105828529_0_34_3&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=15&highlighted_blocks=101416508_105828529_0_34_3&hpos=15&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=101416508_105828529_0_34_3__128800&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=;has_campaign_deals_getaway20_customer_label=1#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/ramada-suites-victoria.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=548340701_198584400_0_0_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=16&highlighted_blocks=548340701_198584400_0_0_0&hpos=16&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=548340701_198584400_0_0_0__162099&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/cordis-auckland.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4312114_231885437_0_42_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=17&highlighted_blocks=4312114_231885437_0_42_0&hpos=17&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4312114_231885437_0_42_0__218646&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/surf-and-snow-backpackers.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=24493710_104185625_0_0_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=18&highlighted_blocks=24493710_104185625_0_0_0&hpos=18&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=24493710_104185625_0_0_0__54698&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/copthorne-auckland-anzac-avenue.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4321930_91457160_0_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=19&highlighted_blocks=4321930_91457160_0_2_0&hpos=19&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4321930_91457160_0_2_0__172480&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/kingsgate-parnell.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4324210_91901131_2_42_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=20&highlighted_blocks=4324210_91901131_2_42_0&hpos=20&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4324210_91901131_2_42_0__182434&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/quality-inn-manukau.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4312404_91901050_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=21&highlighted_blocks=4312404_91901050_2_2_0&hpos=21&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4312404_91901050_2_2_0__137340&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/sudima-auckland-airport.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=26733201_91470131_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=22&highlighted_blocks=26733201_91470131_2_2_0&hpos=22&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=26733201_91470131_2_2_0__237100&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/the-spencer-on-byron.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4319437_91457096_2_2_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=23&highlighted_blocks=4319437_91457096_2_2_0&hpos=23&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4319437_91457096_2_2_0__286740&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/oaks-smartstay-on-hobson.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=4316910_248627369_2_1_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=24&highlighted_blocks=4316910_248627369_2_1_0&hpos=24&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=4316910_248627369_2_1_0__235200&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl', 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/nz/vr-queen-street.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1BCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEP2AEB6AEBiAIBqAIDuALAlIX0BcACAQ&sid=5b45c0c12d9b33b60a64410845136296&all_sr_blocks=101673102_248627330_2_34_0&checkin=2020-07-01&checkout=2020-07-15&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hapos=25&highlighted_blocks=101673102_248627330_2_34_0&hpos=25&no_rooms=1&sr_order=popularity&sr_pri_blocks=101673102_248627330_2_34_0__179000&srepoch=1585560104&srpvid=bc6741d37734006e&ucfs=1&from=searchresults\n;highlight_room=#hotelTmpl']
```

**Category**:

```
['Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Aparthotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Motel', 'Aparthotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hostel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Hotel', 'Aparthotel', 'Aparthotel']
```

**Update:**

Change the last few lines of code and see if you get any difference.

```
#Getting the hotel category by opening each hotel link

category = []

for item in df5['links']:

    driver.get(item)
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2#hp_hotel_name")))

    try:
        job_title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2#hp_hotel_name>span").text
        category.append(job_title)
    except:
        category.append("None")


print(category)
```

Comment: I am checking now.

Comment: I am getting this error message "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class = 'bui-badge bh-property-type bh-property-type--constructive-dark']"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)"

Comment: The code is working and it's not throwing any error. Thanks. However, the results are not correct when I cross-checked the hotels. For example, the hotel " ibis Budget Auckland Airport " the website shows the category "hotel" but results show "Motel". Another example, the hotel "Airport Garden Inn Hotel & Conference Centre" the website shows the category "Hotel" but the results show "Aparthotel".

Comment: Can you please advise why it's showing different categories?

Comment: I think it's not reading Aparthotel category which lies in the class"bui-badge bh-property-type bh-property-type--constructive-dark" Instead Aparthhotel, it gives hotel. Every time re-run the code it shows different results.

Comment: It's working. I used Firefox. Changed to Google chrome. Now it is working.

Comment: Hi, I have another issue which I asked in seperate post. Can you please help me? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940942/some-data-are-not-appearing-while-scrapping-using-for-loop-in-selenium-python)